# Find all commits between two Linux kernel releases

Tags: linux, git

I'm trying to find and list down all commits made between two Linux kernel releases/tags (between Linux kernel 4.4.0 and 4.9.273), inside the git clone of the official Linux kernel repo.

Which git command or software tool can help me achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, to list commits, use [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). There are other commands that list commits, but they're for purposes more exotic than what you want.

“Commits made between two [commits]” is a [revision range](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges). The commits in question are the tags [`v4.4`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.4) and [`v4.9.273`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.9.273). Here you're looking for the commits that are in some revision but not in some older revision, which is the simplest form of revision range `OLD..NEW`.

```
git log v4.4..v4.9.273
```

The `git log` command has many options to control the output format, for example `--oneline` to have just one line per commit, `--name-status` if you want to know what files each commit modifies, `--decorate` to show tag and branch names in addition to commit IDs, `--format=%H` to only list commit IDs (useful to then iterate over the commits programmatically), etc.

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It works fine for v4.4..v4.9 but fails for the command you mentioned with : ```fatal: ambiguous argument 'v4.4..v4.9.273': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Comment: @ParthPratimChatterjee Do you have the correct repository fetched? `v4.9.273` exists only in the `stable` repo, not in the `torvalds` repo. You can have multiple remotes in the same clone. To add a remote: `git remote add stable git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git` then `git fetch stable`

Comment: Okay I got it. Thank You so much !